# Multiprocessing in numerical scheme

Tags: python, multiprocessing, networkx, pde

I'm trying to code in Python a numerical scheme to model a partial differential equation over a network.

I've used  `networkx` to implement the network structure. Now I would like to use `Multiprocessing` to iterate on a given time-scale the same numerical scheme over each edge. Every edge has a matrix `E` such that `E[n,:]` is the state at time `n`.

I tried with this:

```
def Scheme(G):
   NUM_WORKERS = 4
   for n in range(0,M): #time iteration
      with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=NUM_WORKERS) as pool:
          for edge in G.edges: #iteration edges
              results = pool.map_async(Single_Scheme,(edge,n))
              results.wait()

   return G
```

Here `Single_Scheme` is the algorithm over the edge which updates the state at time n+1.

The previous code returns me `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`.

Why am I getting this error?

Edit: I try to add all the necessary details.

`Single_Scheme` function is defined as follows:

```
def Single_Scheme(graph, edge, time):
    V1=edge[0]
    V2=edge[1]
    if not V1 in W:
        l=dt/graph[V1][V2]['dx']
        V=Speed(graph,V1,V2,n)
        if V1 in S:
            graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n+1,0] = graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n,0]*(1 - l*V[0])
    else: 
        graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n+1,0] = graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n,0]*(1 - l*V[0])
        for V0 in list(graph.pred[V1]):
            flux_prec = Speed(graph,V0,V1,n)[-1]
            graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n+1,0]= graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n+1,0] + l*P[V0,V1,V2]*graph[V0][V1]['ev_matrix'][n,-1]*flux_prec
    graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n+1,1:graph[V1][V2]['N']] = graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n,1:graph[V1][V2]['N']] - l*(V[1:graph[V1][V2]['N']]*graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n,1:graph[V1][V2]['N']] - V[0:graph[V1][V2]['N']-1]*graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n,0:graph[V1][V2]['N']-1])

    return graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix'][n+1,:]
```

Here `graph[V1][V2]['ev_matrix][n,:]` is the state on edge `(V1,V2)` at time-step `n`.

Into the main, it's called in the following way:

```
%matplotlib inline

import multiprocessing
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from networkx.algorithms import topological_sort


G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([0,1,2,3,4])
S=[1,2]
W=[3,4]
G.add_edges_from([(1,0),(2,0),(0,3),(0,4)])
G[1][0]['lenght']=1
G[2][0]['lenght']=1
G[0][3]['lenght']=1
G[0][4]['lenght']=1
n_nodes=nx.number_of_nodes(G)
P=np.zeros((n_nodes,n_nodes,n_nodes))
P[1,0,3]=0.5 
P[1,0,4]=0.5


for node in list(topological_sort(G)):
   for next_n in list(G.succ[node]):
       G[node][next_n]['ev_matrix']= np.zeros((51,1001))


G[1][0]['ev_matrix'][0,4*int(np.floor(G[1][0]['N']/10)):6*int(np.floor(G[1][0]['N']/10))] = 1
G[2][0]['ev_matrix'][0,2*int(np.floor(G[2][0]['N']/4)):3*int(np.floor(G[2][0]['N']/4))]=1
G=Scheme(G)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation and show how you run this code in a way that reproduces the error.

Comment: I have updated.